# Unable to detect ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_UP touch events

Tags: android, events, touch-event

I am having trouble detecting the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP events. I am intending to have a button when you press and hold, it automatically decreases an associated value, however I have not gotten to that point in coding because I cannot detect the UP event.

```
for (int position = 0; position < mListItems.size(); position++) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    PilotSkillRow row = (PilotSkillRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pilotskillrow, mSkillListView, false);
    Button skillminus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.skillminus);
    skillminus.setOnTouchListener(new SkillButtonTouchListener(position, false));
    ....
}
```

I understand returning true on the on touch events means that the later ontouch events such as ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP should fire.

```
private class SkillButtonTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    public SkillButtonTouchListener(int pos, boolean plus) {
         ...
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
        int action = motionevent.getActionMasked();

        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.e("a", "MOVE EVENT");
                ....
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("a", "UP EVENT");
                ....
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("a", "DOWN EVENT");
                ....
                return true;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the code, the DOWN even it displayed, but the MOVE and UP EVENTS simply are never displayed. Could it be related to the fact I have an inflated layout?

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Update: If I use the android debugger to connect to the button to check what is happening, the UP event fires when I step through after pressing the button. Probably because there is another process consuming the UP event?

Update 2: The problem is that the textview inside an inflated layout refuses to update. When I perform an invalidate event on the adapter, it will stop the currently processing touch events (no errors). I have another textview which I am able to manually update without the need of the adapter and this does not cause any problems. So it seems to be a problem specific towards RelativeLayout. I have a workaround to only invalidate the data during the ACTION_UP event but I'd rather update the textview on the fly.

Comment: Wasn't working because I was also changing the text in another view inside the inflated layout.

Comment: Seems that if you use the setText() on a textview, any views tied to it via a relativelayout (toLeftOf, toRightOf etc) lose their touch events.